# Access denied to login in mysql from remote system using virtual ip

Tags: mysql

I am implementing Highavailability in mysql with two nodes.
I created an virtual ip (192.168.1.175). 
Now from third system I am trying to connect to mysql using command

```
 mysql -h 192.168.1.175 -u root -pserver02
```

I am getting error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.44' (using password: YES)
```

Now i searched for the problem and found that root does not have permission to login from ip 192.168.1.44 and from ip 175 and I will have to grant permission to ip 44 from ip 175.

Now when I login through ip 175( in the same system whose virtual ip is this) and give permission for ip 44 using command

```
grant all privileges on . to root@'%' identified by 'server02'
```

I am getting the error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.175' (using password: YES)
```

I have to test my fali over mechanism by loging from ip 44 to virtual ip 175.
Now how can i resolve this Accessed denied problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the step where you allow the user to **connect**.

Try running

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

or if that fails

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

The crendtials are managed in a bit of a chaotic way in mysql, but it's **very**, **very** flexible,

Comment: I was making a mistake too. I was not using the flush privileges command